# Scala Worksheet Evaluating Old Code

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am fairly new to Scala so I apologize if this question seems trivial. 
I am using Scala worksheets to evaluate some classes I've written, and it appears that the worksheet I am using does not evaluate the most recently compiled code.

For example,

I have a method which does the following:

```
def randomPermute(xs: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
    randomSelect(xs.length, xs)
}
```

which, upon initial compilation and evaluation of a basic list, produced:

```
List('f, 'a, 'c, 'd, 'b, 'e)
```

However, after I changed this method to

```
def randomPermute(xs: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
    //randomSelect(xs.length, xs)
    Nil
}
```

Upon re-evaluating with the worksheet, I still get a random permutation of the list.

Is there a mistake I'm making in my project settings?

Do I just understand Scala incorrectly?

Note: I am using IntelliJ Idea CE 15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an open ticket for this in the bug tracker, it's been open since January without any comment from the devs, so I wouldn't hold my breath for a fix.

[Link to the open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8121)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that I created a new IntelliJ project and copied all of my files over manually. My new project worked fine with the worksheets. This implies that something artifactory/my project settings was messing with worksheet compilation.

If your project is relatively small it might be fine to just recreate the idea project